# Is it possible, and how to upload a file folder with a google drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Is it possible, and how to upload a file folder with a google drive API, keeping the directory hierarchy?
Example (local):

```
root_dir\
--dir1\
----file
----file
----file
--dir2\
----file
--dir3\
----file
----file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to use Drive Insert to create the folders, then Insert with media content to upload each file, specifying the appropriate Folder ID as the parent. Details and example code is here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert